# Eliminar subconsulta de una subconsulta

Tags: sql, oracle, datatables, select

Hola tengo una **query** y quiero obtener una *query equivalente* llevando todo al **from**. **¿Es posible eliminar una subconsulta que esta dentro de otra subconsulta?**. Lo encare de la siguiente manera pero creo que estoy fallando en el paso 3 y 4 o en la creación de tablas parciales como muestro abajo.

### **Query Original**

```
FROM   obligaciones@dbl_cldd
AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT  *
                  FROM       obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
                  WHERE     oo.obn_fecha_baja IS NULL
                  AND         oo.obn_oga_id IN (SELECT      og.oga_id
                                               FROM        obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
                                               WHERE      og.oga_fecha_baja IS NULL
                                               AND         og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
                                               AND         og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo
                                               AND         og.oga_periodo >= '2015'
                                               AND         og.OGA_ICP_CCO_ID IN ('101','201','601','701','581','582')) 
                  AND         oo.obn_peo_id_material NOT IN ('PC','GEJ')
                  AND         NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                         FROM movimientos_cuenta_corriente@dbl_cldd mcc
                                         WHERE mcc.mcc_fecha_baja IS NULL 
                                         AND mcc.mcc_obn_id = o.obn_id 
                                         AND mcc.mcc_tipo_origen IN ('PAO','FAO','CRE','PSV'))
                  AND         oo.OBN_CUOTA NOT IN (50,80,81,90,91,45)
                  AND         oo.obn_objeto_id = o.obn_objeto_id
                  AND         oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id = o.obn_tipo_objeto_id
                  AND         oo.obn_periodo = o.obn_periodo);
```

### Proceso de transformacion

**1er Paso**: Eliminar **NOT EXIST** principal y llevar la tabla **obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo** arriba con todos sus filtros. El **NOT EXIST** se transforma en **LEFT JOIN** y se agregan los **IS NULL** de los campos que corresponde al **ON**

```
FROM   obligaciones@dbl_cldd
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   *
          FROM      obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
          WHERE     oo.obn_fecha_baja IS NULL
          AND       oo.obn_peo_id_material NOT IN ('PC','GEJ')
          AND       oo.OBN_CUOTA NOT IN (50,80,81,90,91,45)
          AND       oo.obn_oga_id IN (SELECT      og.oga_id
                                     FROM        obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
                                     WHERE      og.oga_fecha_baja IS NULL
                                     AND         og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
                                     AND         og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo
                                     AND         og.oga_periodo >= '2015'
                                     AND         og.OGA_ICP_CCO_ID IN ('101','201','601','701','581','582'))
          AND       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                               FROM movimientos_cuenta_corriente@dbl_cldd mcc
                               WHERE mcc.mcc_fecha_baja IS NULL 
                               AND mcc.mcc_obn_id = o.obn_id 
                               AND mcc.mcc_tipo_origen IN ('PAO','FAO','CRE','PSV')))oo
ON        (           oo.obn_objeto_id = o.obn_objeto_id
          AND         oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id = o.obn_tipo_objeto_id
          AND         oo.obn_periodo = o.obn_periodo)    
WHERE     (     oo.obn_objeto_id IS NULL
          AND   oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id IS NULL
          AND   oo.obn_periodo  )
```

**2do paso:** bajo los filtros al **WHERE** de la tabla **obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo** que tiene **IN** y **NOT EXISTS**

```
FROM   obligaciones@dbl_cldd
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   oo.obn_objeto_id,oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id,oo.obn_periodo
          FROM      obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
          WHERE     oo.obn_fecha_baja IS NULL
          AND       oo.obn_peo_id_material NOT IN ('PC','GEJ')
          AND       oo.OBN_CUOTA NOT IN (50,80,81,90,91,45))oo
ON        (           oo.obn_objeto_id = o.obn_objeto_id
          AND         oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id = o.obn_tipo_objeto_id
          AND         oo.obn_periodo = o.obn_periodo)    
WHERE     (     oo.obn_objeto_id IS NULL
          AND   oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id IS NULL
          AND   oo.obn_periodo  ) 
AND       oo.obn_oga_id IN (SELECT     og.oga_id
                           FROM        obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
                           WHERE       og.oga_fecha_baja IS NULL
                           AND         og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
                           AND         og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo
                           AND         og.oga_periodo >= '2015'
                           AND         og.OGA_ICP_CCO_ID IN ('101','201','601','701','581','582')) 
AND       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM movimientos_cuenta_corriente@dbl_cldd mcc
                     WHERE mcc.mcc_fecha_baja IS NULL 
                     AND mcc.mcc_obn_id = o.obn_id 
                     AND mcc.mcc_tipo_origen IN ('PAO','FAO','CRE','PSV') ;
```

**3er Paso**: Convierto el **IN** en un **JOIN**

```
SELECT OBN_ID
FROM   obligaciones@dbl_cldd
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   oo.obn_objeto_id,oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id,oo.obn_periodo
          FROM      obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
          WHERE     oo.obn_fecha_baja IS NULL
          AND       oo.obn_peo_id_material NOT IN ('PC','GEJ')
          AND       oo.OBN_CUOTA NOT IN (50,80,81,90,91,45))oo
ON        (           oo.obn_objeto_id = o.obn_objeto_id
          AND         oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id = o.obn_tipo_objeto_id
          AND         oo.obn_periodo = o.obn_periodo) 
JOIN      (SELECT     og.oga_id,og.oga_icp_ipo_id,og.oga_periodo
          FROM        obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
          WHERE       og.oga_fecha_baja IS NULL
          AND         og.oga_periodo >= '2015'
          AND         og.OGA_ICP_CCO_ID IN ('101','201','601','701','581','582'))og 
ON        (      og.oga_id= oo.obn_oga_id
          AND    og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
          AND    og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo)                   
WHERE     (     oo.obn_objeto_id IS NULL
          AND   oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id IS NULL
          AND   oo.obn_periodo  ) 
AND       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM movimientos_cuenta_corriente@dbl_cldd mcc
                     WHERE mcc.mcc_fecha_baja IS NULL 
                     AND mcc.mcc_obn_id = o.obn_id 
                     AND mcc.mcc_tipo_origen IN ('PAO','FAO','CRE','PSV') ;
```

**4to Paso**: Transformo el **NOT EXIST** en **LEFT JOIN**

```
SELECT OBN_ID
FROM   obligaciones@dbl_cldd
LEFT JOIN (SELECT     oo.obn_objeto_id,oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id,oo.obn_periodo
          FROM        obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
          WHERE       oo.obn_fecha_baja IS NULL
          AND         oo.obn_peo_id_material NOT IN ('PC','GEJ')
          AND         oo.OBN_CUOTA NOT IN (50,80,81,90,91,45))oo
ON        (           oo.obn_objeto_id = o.obn_objeto_id
          AND         oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id = o.obn_tipo_objeto_id
          AND         oo.obn_periodo = o.obn_periodo) 
JOIN      (SELECT     og.oga_id,og.oga_icp_ipo_id,og.oga_periodo
          FROM        obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
          WHERE       og.oga_fecha_baja IS NULL
          AND         og.oga_periodo >= '2015'
          AND         og.OGA_ICP_CCO_ID IN ('101','201','601','701','581','582'))og 
ON        (      og.oga_id= oo.obn_oga_id
          AND    og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
          AND    og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT     mcc.mcc_obn_id 
          FROM        movimientos_cuenta_corriente@dbl_cldd mcc
          WHERE       mcc.mcc_fecha_baja IS NULL 
          AND         mcc.mcc_obn_id = o.obn_id 
          AND         mcc.mcc_tipo_origen IN ('PAO','FAO','CRE','PSV'))mcc
ON        mcc.mcc_obn_id = o.obn_id                                       
WHERE     (     oo.obn_objeto_id IS NULL
          AND   oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id IS NULL
          AND   oo.obn_periodo  ) 
AND mcc.mcc_obn_id IS NULL;
```

### Creación de tablas parciales

Cuando creo tablas parciales de la query equivalente obtengo 0 registros cuando la query original tiene 4 millones. Algo estoy haciendo mal.
Creando tablas parciales

```
CREATE TABLE b_1 AS
SELECT o.OBN_ID,o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID,o.obn_periodo,oo.obn_oga_id AS oo_obn_oga_id
FROM   obligaciones@dbl_cldd o
LEFT JOIN (SELECT     oo.obn_objeto_id,oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id,oo.obn_periodo
          FROM        obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
          WHERE       oo.obn_fecha_baja IS NULL
          AND         oo.obn_peo_id_material NOT IN ('PC','GEJ')
          AND         oo.OBN_CUOTA NOT IN (50,80,81,90,91,45))oo
ON        (           oo.obn_objeto_id = o.obn_objeto_id
          AND         oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id = o.obn_tipo_objeto_id
          AND         oo.obn_periodo = o.obn_periodo) 
WHERE     (     oo.obn_objeto_id IS NULL
          AND   oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id IS NULL
          AND   oo.obn_periodo  )
```

y el resultado de la tabla anterior creo otra tabla

```
CREATE TABLE b_2 AS
SELECT o.*
FROM   b_1 o
JOIN      (SELECT     og.oga_id,og.oga_icp_ipo_id,og.oga_periodo
          FROM        obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
          WHERE       og.oga_fecha_baja IS NULL
          AND         og.oga_periodo >= '2015'
          AND         og.OGA_ICP_CCO_ID IN ('101','201','601','701','581','582'))og 
ON        (      og.oga_id= o.oo_obn_oga_id
          AND    og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
          AND    og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo);
```

y finalmente creo esta tabla

```
CREATE TABLE b_3 AS
SELECT o.*
FROM   b_2 o
LEFT JOIN (SELECT     mcc.mcc_obn_id 
          FROM        movimientos_cuenta_corriente@dbl_cldd mcc
          WHERE       mcc.mcc_fecha_baja IS NULL 
          AND         mcc.mcc_obn_id = o.obn_id 
          AND         mcc.mcc_tipo_origen IN ('PAO','FAO','CRE','PSV'))mcc
ON        mcc.mcc_obn_id = o.obn_id  
WHERE     mcc.mcc_obn_id IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM b_3; --0 registros
```

Comment: _Error en equivalencia_: ¿cuál es realmente el error que estás teniendo? Por favor, pulsá en [edit] y modificá tanto el título como el cuerpo, para describir el error que decís tener.

Comment: @padaleiana MODIFICADO

Comment: Para poder ayudarte necesitaría conocer la estructura de las tablas que intervienen, sus relaciones e indices (preferentemenete los CREATE TABLE), una explicación de que información deseas obtener con la query, y un estimativo de la cantidad de registros por tabla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede funcionar sin tablas parciales:

```
SELECT /*+ DRIVING_SITE(o) */ *
  FROM obligaciones@dbl_cldd o
    LEFT JOIN obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
      ON    oo.obn_objeto_id = o.obn_objeto_id
        AND oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id = o.obn_tipo_objeto_id
        AND oo.obn_periodo = o.obn_periodo
    LEFT JOIN obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
      ON    og.oga_id = oo.obn_oga_id
        AND og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
        AND og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo
    LEFT JOIN movimientos_cuenta_corriente@dbl_cldd mcc
      ON mcc.mcc_obn_id = o.obn_id 
  WHERE oo.obn_objeto_id is null
    AND mcc.mcc_obn_id is null
    AND oo.obn_fecha_baja IS NULL
    AND oo.obn_peo_id_material NOT IN ('PC','GEJ')
    AND oo.OBN_CUOTA NOT IN (50,80,81,90,91,45)
    AND og.oga_fecha_baja IS NULL
    AND og.oga_periodo >= '2015'
    AND og.OGA_ICP_CCO_ID IN ('101','201','601','701','581','582')
    AND mcc.mcc_fecha_baja IS NULL 
    AND mcc.mcc_tipo_origen IN ('PAO','FAO','CRE','PSV')
```

Comment: sabes q ejecutar asi la query tal como esta no termina nunca por que tiene 800millones de registro cada tabla y no puedo hacer nada en la base de datos por que se trata una base de datos de solo lectura. Es por ese motivo q cree tablas parciales pero eso es otro tema

Comment: consulta... el segundo LEFT JOIN que colocaste no seria un JOIN por q la query original aparece un IN y el IN su equivalente es un JOIN?

Comment: otra consulta.. si o si los filtros tiene que estar en el WHERE? no es lo mismo que colocarlo en el FROM?

Comment: Para tus tres dudas/comentarios, depende... Habría que revisar los índices y el plan de ejecución actual. Siempre que existan las condiciones apropiadas se puede evitar una tabla temporal/auxiliar/de agregación. En un principio también me sonó a  `INNER JOIN` con `og`, hasta que noté la relación también con `oo` que es `LEFT`, al no tener mas información (ej. E-R) no queda mas que probar.

Comment: Aunque, 800 millones de registros es una salvajada para un db link, la solución a tu problema podría ir en otra dirección. ¿Los 3 db links apuntan al mismo host?

Comment: Si apunta a un mismo Host, es solo una Base de Datos de solo LECTURA por lo tanto plan de ejecución no se puede como un montón de otras cosas mas. Solución es probar o crear tablas parciales para no esperar tanto tiempo u usando WITH

Comment: Prueba con el cambio que hice, con el *hint* tal y como lo puse la diferencia debe ser considerable. Y si no puedes sacar EXPLAIN, al menos los índices...